# Tfs Microsoft Api is failing to get httpclient to create workitem

Tags: tfs

Could someone please help what does this error means
[image]

is it some connection issue?
operation performed on onpremise tfs server
here i am using TFS personal access token to do authorize operations.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Could you share your code snippet? The error information is vague.

Comment: Hi @CeceDong-MSFT, Thanks for comment and sample solution, TFS Version : 16.122.27102.1

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT, Solution provided working on my local machine, but when i deploy and run executable on server where Visual Studion or TFS not installed it throws the error

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: error message is empty but there is exception trace which i took screen shot added in question already.

Comment: You may try to remove all delete `packages.config` file, remove exist packages, and restore them on the server machine. By the way, how do you run project on the server machine?

Comment: Thanks @CeceDong-MSFT, i'll try your suggestions, I created executable console app which triggers TFS webapi.

Comment: If your issue persists after re-adding the packages, please share your code snippet and how you run it in details, so that we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: How's your issue going? Is it solved?

Comment: Hi @CeceDong-MSFT, sorry for late response, due to error message text was having encoding issue, was not able to figure out the issue, did debug on server and found out tfs url with collection was not forming properly hence it was giving "page not found" error message, after that we fixed it by updating the tfs api url.

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT, sure, thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Due to error message text was having encoding issue, was not able to figure out the issue, Did debug on server and found out TTFS url with collection was not forming properly hence it was giving "page not found" error message, after that we fixed it by updating the tfs api url.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code snippet creating a Bug work item in DevOps using HttpClient library, for your reference:

```
public class CreateBug
    {
        readonly string _uri;
        readonly string _personalAccessToken;
        readonly string _project;

        public CreateBug()
        {
            _uri = "https://xxx.visualstudio.com";
            _personalAccessToken = "xxx";
            _project = "xxxxx";
        }

        public WorkItem CreateBugUsingClientLib()
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri(_uri);
            string personalAccessToken = _personalAccessToken;
            string project = _project;

            VssBasicCredential credentials = new VssBasicCredential("", _personalAccessToken);
            JsonPatchDocument patchDocument = new JsonPatchDocument();

            //add fields and thier values to your patch document
            patchDocument.Add(
                new JsonPatchOperation()
                {
                    Operation = Operation.Add,
                    Path = "/fields/System.Title",
                    Value = "Authorization Errors"
                }
            );

            patchDocument.Add(
                new JsonPatchOperation()
                {
                    Operation = Operation.Add,
                    Path = "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority",
                    Value = "1"
                }
            );

            VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(uri, credentials);
            WorkItemTrackingHttpClient workItemTrackingHttpClient = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();

            try
            {
                WorkItem result = workItemTrackingHttpClient.CreateWorkItemAsync(patchDocument, project, "Bug").Result;

                Console.WriteLine("Bug Successfully Created: Bug #{0}", result.Id);

                return result;
            }
            catch (AggregateException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error creating bug: {0}", ex.InnerException.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }

    }
```